# Install latest R (3.x) on RHEL 5

Tags: r

I'd like to install the latest version of R in RHEL 5 as I tried to install some library (plyr) but it complained a dependency could not be used with my installed version of R: package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)

2.15.2 is the latest precompiled R binary available for RHEL5 from epel. I guess they stopped updating it. Is compiling from source to get R 3.x my only solution here or there is some binary installer somewhere else? I much rather use something like yum since it take care of all the R dependency packages as well.

Comment: No. You can also compile Rcpp for 2.15.2 (see CRAN archives). Which means you have to compile ALL dependencies for that version. Good luck.